# Displaying 'Object' instead of parameter value for SpringMVC + i18n by using MessageSource

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

With SpringMVC, 'Object' name is displaying instead of parameter value. Below is my code.

```
msg("label.key.is.inactive", "Parameter");

label.key.is.inactive = key ''{0}'' is inactive. -- Present in properties file

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

protected String msg(final String msgKey,final Object... params){
  return messageSource.getMessage(msgKey, new Object[]{params}, Locale.US);
}
```

Output: 
**Expected:** key 'Parameter' is inactive.
**Actual:** key '[Ljava.lang.Object;@394a861' is inactive.

Can someone tell me what should be done to get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
return messageSource.getMessage(msgKey, params, Locale.US);
```